# TestFlight Can't add build to Internal Test group

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I have already published my app to the app store. I have already a couple of versions. I created an internal test group and an external test group.

Today, I published a new version of the app to App Store Connect, which I want to add to the internal test group. But somehow, I can't select it. When I go to the Internal Test Group, there is no (+)-Sign next to Builds. When I go to the external Test group, there is. And when I select the build and click on the (+)-Sign next to Groups, I can't select the internal test group.

I checked the build version. I should have incremented it correctly. I also tried to disable the other builds, but it still didn't work.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 4]

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: We recently faced the same issue. Most probably the method that worked for us was to create a new internal user group with manual distribution option and then manually adding the build to group. I am saying "Probably" because I am not sure if our solution fixed the issue or it got fixed on its own after some time. On whole it took around 1.5 hours for us to get the build to TestFlight app after trying different solutions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Okay, it seems the new build is added to Internal Testing automatically, and it just takes some time. So this can be closed.

Comment: how long did it take to be added to the testers?

Comment: it took use recently about 3 hours for apps that we haven't update for over a year.

Answer (score 33):

Filling up the test information solved the problem for me. Go to > Test Flight > Test Information > Review Notes. Just added "Test" and saved it, the build magically appeared right after.

Comment: In my case just description wasn't enough, but adding also marketing and privacy policy urls and contact information helped

Comment: Weird! I kept waiting for 1 day thinking it will resolve itself! Just updating the Test Info, resolved the issue!

Comment: Same here.. Waited for a day, just saw this and tried it, updating the test info resolved it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't now why, but its work

Comment: @Enes what did you do?

Comment: @Berk as he described

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense, i still see the warning icon next to 'Test Information' menu item after adding "test" to review notes, but yes this did indeed force it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Simply create a new internal Group with manual distribution mode. Then you can select Testers and Build to test easily.
Once you have a manual distribution group and testers received build, you can create a new group with automatic distribution.

Comment: Moreover, I got Test Flight notification after 24 hours with my initial automated distribution group. It was weird. Although I had deleted that group.

Answer (score 7):

Test Information => Beta App Description add something here
Test Details => What to Test add something here

then save

Comment: This solved it for me! This clearly is a bug in TestFlight, I already had some text in there, but Internal were greyed out. After editing this text, and saving again, the build directly became available in TF.

Answer (score 4):

If the build is taking too long to be made available, I've found it helpful to submit a new build to re-trigger App Store Connect flows.

Answer (score 2):

The same happened to me as well, looks like a bug in test-flight, what I had to do, to solve this was the following :

1. Create a New External Test Group with one or two internal users itself.
2. Assign the build to this new External Test Group.
3. Right away the same then reflects for internal users also ( wanted to achieve this only ).
4. Delete the External Test Group created in Step 1.

Answer (score 2):

Berk's answer works on our case too. Thanks a lot!

After downloading the version now enabled for AS testers, i noted that Apple added a couple of new screens before our app is shown for testing. More like splash screens showing what the developers have said to testers in the Test Info box. In this case it's simply "test".

Looks like a bug on testflight that should have made this compulsory before allowing ppl to upload a build.

Comment: This should be a comment to the referenced answer, instead of an answer on itself :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution by re-editting or adding the Test information works for me.
In my case, the internal test group is greyed out, so I tried to create a manual test group and add it to the build. Though the manual test group showed up,the new build is still not refreshed in TestFlight. Then I tried re-editting the description of Test Information and save, the new build was immediately available. Now both the auto & manual test group are good to download new build.